# Reload specific page whenever it is visited?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview, refresh, back

I am trying to figure out the best way to reload a specific page when using the back button in xcode.  Here is what I have right now

```
-(IBAction)backButton {
 [webView goBack];
 [webView reload];

 }
```

All I want to have happen, is instead of refreshing every page when tapping the back button, I only want my local html to be refreshed, so something like

```
 -(IBAction)backButton {
 [webView goBack];
 if ("url matches localHTML"){
 [webView reload];
 }
 }
```

The localHTML that I want refreshed is only the homepage.  I know the solution wouldn't be as simple as above, but I'm just trying to show you what I'm looking for.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: are all pages being viewed in this webview going to be in the same domain or local on the device?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann The home page would be the localHTML that I want to be reloaded, and the rest would be on a different domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked out the delegate method [UIWebViewDelegate webView: shouldStartLoadWithRequest: navigationType:]?

Seems like you could return NO (i.e. don't load) if the URL in the request doesn't match one you want to allow.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

And if you want to only refresh the local HTML, do something like:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSURL * urlWeAreConsidering = [request URL];
    if([urlWeAreConsidering isFileURL] == NO)
    { 
        // sends off a separate request
        [webView loadRequest: [NSURL URLWithString: @"file://LocalURL"]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

And if you're also working with a different domain, you can probably work with and around the code snippet I've written up there to permit initial fetches from that domain.

Comment: I ended up using a variation of this, the uiwebview delegate methods were very helpful